# checking for nothing warns that I might be using unitialised variables. Ways to suppress?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

In visual studio 2008, when I use something akin to the following snippet:

```
Dim myVar
.... ' all sorts of stuff that might initialise myVar '
if not isNothing(myVar) then
   myVar = new Object()
end if
myVar.ToString()
```

visual studio warns me on the last statement that myVar might be uninitialised, and a nullreference exception could occur.

To me it seems desirable to suppress that message in this situation.

1. Am I right in wanting to suppress that warning here, or am I overlooking something?
2. Is it possible to suppress a warning here.

Note that I don't want to suppress the warning in general, only if I'm sure it makes no sense here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I right in wanting to suppress that warning here, or am I overlooking something?

No you are not right. If there's a condition under witch the variable might not get initialized you will get into trouble. So it would be better to always initialize variables:

```
Dim myVar as SomType = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you change the line:

```
Dim myVar
```

To:

```
Dim myVar = Nothing
```

The warning will go away.

Another issue though is that you really shouldn't declare stuff as `Dim myVar`, it should be `Dim myVar As Object` in that case. You should always set [Option Explicit On](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f%28VS.80%29.aspx) in VB.Net. It'll save you from a lot of potential hard to find bugs in the future.